# Error CS0029 on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

i'm porgramming a little application, i have a textbox named **"txtFormula"**
and i want that if the user put the text **"Velocidad"** on it there appears an answer

```
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string formulas;
        formulas = txtFormula.Text;
        if (txtFormula.Text = "Velocidad")
        {
            txtFormula.Hide();
            label1.Hide();
            pictureBox1.Hide();
        }
    }
```

The error is on "if (txtFormula.Text = "Velocidad"), it gives me the error CS0029 "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool' "
Thanks...

Comment: You have a typo: `txtFormula.Text = "Velocidad"` should be `txtFormula.Text == "Velocidad"`. `==` is the equality operator in C#; `=` is an assignment operator.

Answer (score 2):

it should be

```
 if (txtFormula.Text == "Velocidad")
```

instead of

```
 if (txtFormula.Text = "Velocidad")
```

As `==` is a equality operator and `=` is assigning operator. For example.

```
int x = 2;
int y = 2;

if(x==y){
   //it would run here
   x = 3;
   y = x;
   //now y == 3
}
```